# Rails 6, float or bigint column types being treated as integer by ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I need to accept very large integer values on a postgres column on a table `pre_transaction`. The column name is `give_amount`.

I tried changing the column type to `bigint` with:

`change_column :pre_transactions, :give_amount, :bigint`

but I still get the following error when I try to save the record even after restarting the console:

```
ActiveModel::RangeError (1000000000000000000000 is out of range for ActiveModel::Type::Integer with limit 8 bytes)
```

I also realized that if I run `PreTransaction` in the rails console, the bigint columns are shown as `integer` columns (same for foreign keys that are stated as bigint in the schema but appear as integer on rails c), which is weird.

That's why I then changed the column type to `float`. Now when I run `PreTransaction` in the rails console I do see the column as type `float` but now when I try to save the record it saves, but rounding up to 1.0.

So, how can I do to store very large integers in the database?

Comment: What database do you use?

Comment: Postgresql as I stated above

Comment: oups sorry misread

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `:bigint` use the `:decimal` type. It avoids float rounding inconsistencies and allows for large numbers to be ok.